# Alignment in a Table throught vba excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem with Aligment in a table, which I creating via vba excel. The code works but it doesn't change the formating in the table. The selection is working.

```
 objTable.Columns(5).Select
 With objWord.Selection
    HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
 End With

 Create a Word document with table via vba excel:
 Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
 objWord.Visible = True
 objWord.Activate
 Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add(path)
 Set objRange = objDoc.Range
 objRange.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
 objDoc.Tables.Add objRange, number_row, number_column
 Set objTable = objDoc.Tables(2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a reference set to the Word object library, you need something like:

```
objTable.Columns(5).Select
 With objWord.Selection
    .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
    .Cells.VerticalAlignment = wdCellAlignVerticalCenter
 End With
```

Note that you use Word's constants, not Excel's.

Comment: First line work, but dosent change in a table, second line i have error "Unable to set the VerticalAlignment property of the Range class"

Comment: There was a typo in the code which I have now fixed for the second line. Do you have a reference set to the Word object library?

Comment: I added references libraru Microsoft Word, according to this Manual: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264402.aspx and Working!!